# Why am I getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word"?

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, metamask

I am creating a website using the metamask ethereum API. But for some reason, I am getting this error on line 8:
`const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();`
The thing is that I copied this code straight from the API website, so I don't know why it is recieving an error
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#using-the-provider
Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Are you writing `await` in a non-async function?

Comment: In the documentation you have linked, they are indeed using await outside of an async function. Weird. You can try copying the entrie file inside an async IIFE `(async function() { const provider = await detectEthereumProvider(); // rest of the code  })()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword must be called within an async function:

```
async function main()
{
    // Place your code here.
}
// Then, call that async function that wraps your code:
main();
```