# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word in a {name} file

Tags: javascript

I'm in a weird situation where I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word (at addLocalSkillset.js?t=1654154827218:28:21)`, I tried to remove the headers variable, and URL variable, but still that error is found.

In fact, if you see the file, No reserved word is being used, isn't that weird?

```js
import { API_URL, API_KEY } from '../../../@constants/Global/Env';

const addLocalSkillset = (workSpaceId) => {

    const newSkillset = {
        skills_group: `Untitled ${Math.random().toString().substring(2, 5)}`,
        skills_set: [],
        workSpaceId: workSpaceId,
    };

    const _URL = `${API_URL}/predefinedskills`;

    const _headers = {
        'api-key': API_KEY,
        'user-token': token,
    };

    var body = new FormData();
    body.append('predefinedSkills', JSON.stringify(newSkillset));

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: _headers,
        body: body,
    };

  try {
    const request = await fetch(_URL, requestOptions);
    const response = await request.json();
    console.log('result', response);

    if (response.status === true) {
      return {
        data: res.data,
        status: true,
        message: 'Succesfully added a skill set.',
      };
    } else {
      return {
        status: false,
        message: "Something wen't wrong adding a skill set.",
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: false,
      message: "Something wen't wrong adding a skill set.",
    };
  }
}

export default addLocalSkillset;
```

Comment: Could it be the fact that you are using `await` inside a NOT `async` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63951837/why-am-i-getting-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-reserved-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add async when declaring the function just before the variables

```
const addLocalSkillset = async (workSpaceId) => {
```